# How to setup Cron on Godaddy in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I want to run schedule on Godaddy server but it's don't work
I used this Cron:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/MyUserName/public_html/ticket.shofoffer.com/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Kernel.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\ChangeStatus;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\ChangeStatus',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('change:status')->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

ChangeStatus.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Complaints;
use Illuminate\support\facades\DB;
use App\Tickets;

class ChangeStatus extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'change:status';
    protected $description = 'This will change the status of complaint';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('tickets')
            ->whereDate( 'updated_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays( 2 ) )
            ->where('status', 'open')
            ->update(['status' =>'pending']);
        echo "done";
        DB::table('tickets')
            ->whereDate( 'updated_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays( 15 ) )
            ->where('status', 'replied')
            ->update(['status' =>'closed']);

        echo "done";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest piping the output of the cron to a file to see what there errors are.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to piping the output to file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By piping the output of the cron command to a file, you can check the output/errors that are being generated and fix the issue.

```
*   *   *   *   *   path/to/app/artisan schedule:run > path/to/app/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

In your case, try something like:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/MyUserName/public_html/ticket.shofoffer.com/artisan schedule:run > /home/MyUserName/public_html/ticket.shofoffer.com/cron.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you for your helping, I'll try it now

Comment: Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' change:status > '/dev/null' 2>&1

Comment: That was the result

Comment: That means that the cron in running correctly. Have you checked your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file for any errors?

Comment: No, Not yet, I'll check now

Comment: Does I need to change the time to be every 30MIN

Comment: So based on the output in the `cron.txt` file, your cron is executing the command correctly every minute. That means, either there's an error in your code (in which case there should be an exception in the log file) or it's running correctly but not doing what you expect.

Comment: Yes you are right however thank you man for your time and your helping :)

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)